# Android - SQLite - Relationship many to many

Tags: java, android, sqlite, dao, pojo

I would like to submit a question about serialization through SQLite when I was trying to create a DB scheme using many to many relationship between two entities :

- Order
- Product
- OrderBill (Order - Product)

I would like to link Order and Product with OrderBill's:

- OrderBill keeps id of Order, id of Product, quantity ordered.
- Order keeps, for example, just a name
- Product keeps a name and a price

I created my Pojos for Order, Product and OrderBill.
But for OrderBill having as attributes:

- long id_order_bill
- Order order
- Product product

But I'm stucking with the use of these entities. Doing so, I need to keep three List:

- List `<OrderBill>`
- List `<Order>`
- List `<Product>`

If I want to get the product's list of an order, I just need to do retrieve all Products of the `List<OrderBill>` which has `Order = order`.

But I need to maintain these informations :

```
public class DataStore {

    private List<Order> myOrders;
    private List<Product> myProducts;
    private List<OrderBill> myOrderBills;
    public void add_product(Order o, Product p, int quantity) {
         myOrderBills.add(new OrderBill(o,p,quantity));
    }
```

In my `DAO` I do like so :

```
public OrderBill insert(OrderBill o) {
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(COL_NAME_ID_ORDER, o.getOrder().getId());
values.put(COL_NAME_ID_PRODUCT, o.getProduct().getId());
values.put(COL_NAME_QUANTITY, o.getQuantity());

long id = db.insert(TABLE_ORDER_BILL, null, values);
o.setId_order_bill(id);
return o;
}
```

With `DAO` pattern, I'm converting Product and Order of a `OrderBill` object to id_product and id_order, am I doing it right? I didn't test, but I would like to know if it's a good way to keep many to many relationship in DB AND in my app?

Because in my app, I would like to permit several Orders to be linked with several products, but not duplicating number of equivalent products.

Do you see another way to process?

Comment: This looks correct. Why do you think it wouldn't be?

Comment: Serialization of data gives me some difficulties to implement. I need to check if it wouldn't be a problem for IDs for each entities. I'll give feedback or my project.

Comment: Sorry I didn't have much time to test my solution. Tomorrow I'll.
But the main potential issue would be to read / create IDs for entities:
Scenario 1: Serialization
- insert an order in DB (retrieve ID)
- insert the product in DB (retrieve ID)
- insert the order_bill in DB (with the two previously generated IDs)

Scenario 2: Deserialization
- Read and create order_bills
- Read each orders
- Read each products

Do you think that deleting all entries in DB after a scenario 2 is good? I'm afraid to get lost with generated IDs...